# Hide menu home slider and active it when page scroll down

Tags: html, css

How to hide menu on the home slider and active it when page scrolls down. Currently, menus are displaying on the slider and when scrolling also its displaying. But here I want it to hide menu on the slider. How can I hide that?

[image]

On the image, I want to hide that menu.

I tried out some CSS. but after scrolling also it's not showing.

```
.menu-bar-wrapper:not(.float-header)
    display: none;
}

.menu-bar-wrapper:not(.is-sticky) {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more explanatory and attach a fiddle or something to help your question out.

Comment: Please provide complete code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @ Mohammed Wahed Khan, @Kamil Naja  I updated my question with website link.

Comment: Please post code here, link is not enough

Comment: This is a WordPress website. so I added that above css to hide that menu section on the image. but after scrolling also it's hiding the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added javascript for that page. Its working fine for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                        (function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){

                // hide .navbar first
                $(".top_nav").hide();

                // fade in .navbar
                $(function () {
                                $(window).scroll(function () {
            // set distance user needs to scroll before we fadeIn navbar
                                                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                                                                $('.top_nav').fadeIn();
                                                } else {
                                                                $('.top_nav').fadeOut();
                                                }
                                });


                });

});
  }(jQuery));                   });             
                </script>
```

Comment: Good to see you got that working. Did you check my code?

Comment: @ Mohammed Wahed Khan. ya. but still, I can see navigation is displaying before scrolling also in your code. Anyway thanks for ur time.

Comment: I have put that navigation as your default you can remove it. Any which ways good  to hear you got it solved.

Answer (score 0):

to hide menu at top of page

```
.top_nav.affix-top
    {
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    }
```

after that it becomes .top_nav.affix not .top_nav.affix-top

.menu-bar-wrapper doesn't seem to be a thing.

You can work this out by right clicking and choosing "inspect element" from the menu that pops up.

Comment: this will make the height of nav to `0` on scroll too.

Comment: If I add above CSS its hiding another menu also which is showing after scrolling down. CSS is taking both the menu. but only on the image menu should hide.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) the menu and logo and write separate CSS for them then add a sub-class as header-fixed which will have `display: none;` and `display: block;` properties which will make your menu visible on the scroll and hide it when on top of the page.

Comment: Using CSS and jquery also needs to add or the only CSS. can u share the code?.... Anyone knows please share the code. in my understanding, I tried all the possibilities of CSS.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Wahed98666/pen/BqELep try this, I have made the code work you just need to add css as per your requirement. I cloned the menu so that if you add it in the main menu it will replicate in the fixed menu too. Hope it works. ;-)

Comment: thanks for your valuable time. i checked ur code. The default menu is displaying. but I want to hide menu. after scrolling menu should display.

Comment: @jacklin I have made the required changes not check it out

Comment: @jacklin Can you check the code and reply to the last comment